# Django rest framework if serializer returns empty

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have am implementing a follower and followers system in my drf api.

My relationship model and serializer:

**models.py**

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="primary_user", null=True, blank=True)
    related_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="related_user", null=True, blank=True)
    incoming_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=RELATIONSHIP_CHOICE, default=RELATIONSHIP_CHOICE[0])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " " + self.incoming_status + " " + self.related_user.username
```

**serializers.py**

```
class RelationshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    outgoing_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Relationship
        fields = (
            'user',
            'related_user',
            'incoming_status',
            'outgoing_status',
        )

    def get_outgoing_status(self, obj):

        related_user = obj.related_user
        user = obj.user
        try:
            query = models.Relationship.objects.get(user=related_user, related_user=user)
            user_id = query.incoming_status
        except models.Relationship.DoesNotExist:
            user_id = "none"

        return user_id
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['get'], url_path='relationship/(?P<related_pk>\d+)')
    def relationship(self, request, pk, related_pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()

        query = models.Relationship.objects.filter(user=user)&\
                models.Relationship.objects.filter(related_user__pk=related_pk)

        serializer = serializers.RelationshipSerializer(query, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Incoming status is your relationship to the user and outgoing status is the users relationship to you to so for example this can return

```
[
    {
        "user": 2,
        "related_user": 1,
        "incoming_status": "follows",
        "outgoing_status": "none"
    }
]
```

This means you follow the user and the user doesn't follow you back

When you follow a user my code works fine because it returns `"incoming_status": "follows"` and it then checks for the outgoing status in the serializers. However when the:

```
query = models.Relationship.objects.filter(user=user) &
        models.Relationship.objects.filter(related_user__pk=related_pk)
```

query in `views.py` returns null the meaning that the incoming status is none the serializer outputs `[]` because the query is empty. How do I make `incoming_status = "none"` if the query is empty?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well if the query in your views.py returns empty queryset then there is no data to be serialized and your RelationshipSerializer will not return any data.

Comment: Ya because the user is not found in the follower database thus it returns null . The question is how do I serialize a dictionary with the values [{"incoming_status: "none"}] to pass to my serializer if the query returns null @ShiftN'Tab

Comment: Then why dont you just simply use conditional expression on your `query` if  `None` and not null actually,  then add a `context = [{'incoming_status: 'none''}];` to your `return Response(context);`

Comment: ya that would work but then the `outgoing_status` function in my serializer wont run @ShiftN'Tab

Comment: please post what is the expected output

Comment: `[
    {
        "user": 2,
        "related_user": 1,
        "incoming_status": "none",
        "outgoing_status": "follows"
    }
]` . @ShiftN'Tab